# What are those empty partitions on my UEFI/GPT partitioned disk for?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, gpt

I'd like to know what's with all those unnamed partitions. I've always thought they are what they say they are (recoveries and what not), why are there so many of them?

And why do they all say 100% free (i.e. they're all empty!)
If that's the case, what happened to my recovery?

Info:
I'm on Dell Inspiron 7520
Windows 8 Single Language

(Had Kali installed on SSD a couple days ago, now I've just deleted that and will install Kali on VM on SSD, that's drive (S:).

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those partitions are not empty. They might look that way, but they're not. You see them because your HDD is partitioned using the [UEFI/GPT scheme](http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/38633-recovery-partition-windows-8-a.html#post327323).

If you want, you could check what each of these individual partitions are for by using `DISKPART`
Start the command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → "cmd" → OK) and type `diskpart` and press Enter.

Use these commands:

```
diskpart list disk
select disk 0
list partition
select partition 1
detail partition
```

You might see something like:

```
Partition 1
Type    : de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac ← the GUID
Hidden  : Yes
Required: Yes
Attrib  : 0X8000000000000001
Offset in Bytes: 1048576

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 7         WINRE_DRV    NTFS   Partition   1000 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

Select different partitions using the `select partiton <NUMBER>` command and thereafter the `detail partition` command and look up the [partition type GUIDs on Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) and you'll know what they are for.

For instance, `de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac` is the Windows Recovery Environment partition.

Comment: Since you said you have a Dell machine, I'll assume one of those recovery partitions contain Dell's proprietary recovery software (I'm pretty sure it's the one with the PDR_IMAGE label). The one with the WINRETOOLS label contains WindowsRE and is used typically when your computer crashes and you want to use system restore, automatic repair, etc. on your Windows installation. I'm not so sure about the other partitions, but you could probably take a look at what's inside by using the "partition explore" feature of partition management software like MiniTool or Easus Partition Master

Comment: Well, I've deleted my comment so not bother with seemingly useless question. You still answered it.. Can't get anymore awesome, haha. Thank you very much. I'll try those tools as well